# Trigger is not working when comparing specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created this trigger to everytime one column of a table is changed, another column of this table is set "null". This is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MSF_TONKEN_CLEAR]
 ON [dbo].[end]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (ENDNO) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE end
        SET TOKEN = Null
        FROM end e2 INNER JOIN Inserted I ON e2.ID = I.ID
        WHERE I.ENDNO <> c2.ENDNO
    END 
END
```

But it's not working. I update the column "ENDNO" and the TOKEN still there.
If I comment the line

```
--WHERE I.ENDNO <> c2.ENDNO
```

it works, but for every update, not only the update of the column "ENDNO". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `AFTER` trigger.

Your comparison `I.ENDNO <> e2.ENDNO` will always be false, because `INSERTED` values are already in target table. You have to compare with `DELETED`.

```
    UPDATE [end] SET
      TOKEN = Null
    FROM [end] e2
    INNER JOIN DELETED d ON e2.ID = I.ID
    WHERE D.ENDNO <> e2.ENDNO
```

By the way `IF UPDATE (ENDNO)` is almost useless. It will be true even if nothing changed, 
e.g.

```
UPDATE ... SET ENDNO=ENDNO
```

Comment: Thats it. The two values were always equal. You are right. Thank you.